# MySQL: Query that finds all states that does not contain a specific value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with information regarding different places (landmarks/cities etc).

Each row represents one landmark, and amongst the columns, we have state and we have type.

So I want to find all states that does not contain a specific type. Let’s say that does not contain a river.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT state
 FROM mytable
 WHERE state NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT state
   FROM mytable
   WHERE type = 'river'
)
```

Should give you what you want. Of course, it might not be the best way to do it, but it's not like you provided any real information about your model.

Comment: This worked! Thank you ^^